# trouble debugging during runtime

Tags: objective-c, debugging, xcode4.4

I have written a some code for a drill down table app I have been making, but the app crashes only during runtime. Xcode doesn't give me any errors while building the app. The debugger outputs:

> 2012-10-18 10:58:26.513 second[474:c07] -[NavController setItems:]: unrecognized selector >sent to instance 0xc217a00
>   2012-10-18 10:58:26.515 second[474:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NavController setItems:]: unrecognized selector sent >to instance 0xc217a00'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x14b8022 0xeb8cd6 0x14b9cbd 0x141eed0 0x141ecb2 0x3fbe 0xe2a1e 0x41401 0x41670 0x41836 >0xbfc9dd8 0x4872a 0x19596 0x1a274 0x29183 0x29c38 0x1d634 0x13a2ef5 0x148c195 0x13f0ff2 >0x13ef8da 0x13eed84 0x13eec9b 0x19c65 0x1b626 0x1d40 0x1cd9)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

I think I understand that the error lies in NavController.m where:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    MasterViewController* root = (MasterViewController*)self.topViewController;
    NSDictionary* thelist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    root.items = [thelist objectForKey:@"Items"];
    root.navigationItem.title = [thelist objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

btw, I made the array items like this: (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* items;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app crashes, because of the following line:

```
root.items = [thelist objectForKey:@"Items"];
```

This line is just a shortcut for writing:

```
[root setItems:[thelist objectForKey:@"Items"]];
```

And the runtime complains that there is no method `setItems:` found. The reason why there is compile error is because you tell the compiler that `root` is of class `MasterViewController`, however, that is not true. At runtime the obj-c runtime finds out that `root` is in fact of class `NavController` and it seems like `NavController` has no `setItems:` method.

In other words, this line is wrong:

```
MasterViewController* root = (MasterViewController*)self.topViewController;
```

You lie about the class; `self.topViewController` returns an object that is of class `NavController`, yet you force the compiler to treat it as `MasterViewController` which will fail as soon as you call a method that is not found for `NavController`.

Comment: So I would have to change the `MasterViewController* root` to `NavController`? How would the setItems method be implemented? Sorry for the possibly dumb question.

Comment: @user1738193 I don't know the whole code of your project and what you are trying to do in the quoted method at all, I just informed you that topViewController is no MasterViewController. If you say it should be one, then your error is elsewhere (e.g. you assigned the wrong object to this property in interface builder or elsewhere in your code).

Comment: Well it turns out that the problem was in the interface builder. I assigned it, MasterViewController, to the wrong view. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
MasterViewController* root = (MasterViewController*)self.topViewController;
```

`self.topViewController` is proably not an instance of MasterViewController, but a NavController instance and there you go.